# How is this substitution done?

Tags: integration

Consider $$
 {\int{\frac{1}{u^{2} + \frac{3}{4}} d u}} $$

to get to $ \frac{1}{1 + f(x)^2} $, this substitution is applied (the order is questionable, I'll say):
$$ u=\frac{\sqrt{3} v}{2} $$
Then $  du=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} v}{2}\right)^{\prime }dv = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} dv $, 
$ v=\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{3} u $
So
$${\int{\frac{1}{u^{2} + \frac{3}{4}} d u}} ={\int{\frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{3 \left(v^{2} + 1\right)} d v}} $$

Now, how does that substitution work? I can't see how $ \frac{3}{4} $ becomes $ ( v^2 + 1 ) $. May you explain?

Comment: ${\int{\frac{1}{u^{2} + \frac{3}{4}} d u}}=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}}{\int{\frac{1}{(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}u)^{2} +1 } d u}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $u=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}v$ and $du=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\,dv$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{u^{2} + \frac{3}{4}} \,du &=\int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}v\right)^{2} + \frac{3}{4}} \cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\,dv
\\&=\int\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}v^{2} + \frac{3}{4}} \cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\,dv
\\&=\int\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}\left(v^{2} + 1\right)} \cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\,dv
\\&=\int\frac{\sqrt3}{\frac{3}{2}\left(v^{2} + 1\right)}\,dv
\\&=\int\frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{3 \left(v^{2} + 1\right)} \,dv 
\\&=\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}\int\frac1{v^2+1}\,dv
\\&=\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}\arctan(v)+C
\\&=\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}u\right)+C
\\&=\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}u\right)+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: It seems that $u$ gets redefined: isn't that misleading?

Comment: @user294459 I'm not quite sure what you mean, but perhaps you mean now we have an integral in terms of $v$ and $v$ is different from $u$. If that's so, then that's an accurate concern - the way this is dealt with is that we will convert back to $u$ once we have finished evaluating the integral. I'll update my answer to include this

Comment: No, I mean that in the integral we're currently integrating in $u$, which substitutes some $f(x)$. Then we "redefine" $u$ to be $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}v$: isn't that misleading? Mostly because we're defining $u$ in terms of $v$, rather than vice versa. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user294459 Well, in this case it's equivalent - it's the same as saying $v=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}u$. Usually it is stated whichever way round is most convenient: e.g. sometimes you want $\sin(u)=v$ and sometimes you want $u=\sin v$.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more direct way is

$$\int \frac{1}{u^2+3/4} du = \frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}} \int \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} u^2+ 1} du = \frac{4}{3} \int \frac{1}{\left ( \frac{2 u}{\sqrt{3}} \right )^2 + 1} du.$$

Now substitute $v=\frac{2 u}{\sqrt{3}}$ and manage constants as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Take $ u = \sqrt{(3/4)}  tan \theta ==> du = \sqrt{3/4} sec^2 \theta d\theta $

$\int 1/{(u^2+3/4)}du = \int \sqrt{(4/3)} d\theta  = \sqrt{(4/3)} \theta = \sqrt{(4/3)} tan^{-1} \sqrt{(4/3)}.$

Hope this helps!

Shortly,  $\int 1/{(u^2+c)}du = 1/\sqrt c \quad tan^{-1} u$ where $c$ is a constant.

Thanks.